# Перевести код из Python в Java (C++)

Tags: java, python

Есть код на питоне, который нужно перевести в Java (или C++). Т.к. не владею синтаксисом питона, прошу помощи у постояльцев:

```
def insertion_binary(data):
for i in range(1, len(data) - 1):
    key = data[i]
    lo, hi = 0, i - 1
    while lo < hi:
        mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2
        if key < data[mid]:
            hi = mid
        else:
            lo = mid + 1
    for j in range(i, lo + 1, -1):
        data[j] = data[j - 1]
    data[lo] = key
return data
```

Начал делать, вот что получилось:

```
public int[] insertion_binary(int[] data){
for (int i = 1 ; i < data.length ; i++){
    int key = data[i];
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = i - 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш метод будет выглядеть так.

```
public int[] insertion_binary(int[] data){
    for (int i = 1 ; i < data.length ; i++){
        int key = data[i];
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = i - 1;

        while(lo < hi){
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo);
            if (key < data[mid]){
                hi = mid;
            } else {
                lo = mid + 1;
            }
        }

        for (int j = i ; j != lo + 1 ; j--){
            data[j] = data[j - 1];
        }

        data[lo] = key;
    }

    return data;
}
```